# Can I run an 8k display on an M1 Mac, at 30hz?

Tags: macos, display, hdmi, apple-silicon, 4k

I want to buy an M1-based Mac. Tempted by the new 24-inch Imac but I suspect the answer will not change whether it's a Macbook Air, 13-nch Macbook Pro, or Mac Mini, as they all run the same SoC.

Can I run an 8k display on it?

I understand that a [6k monitor is supported at 60hz](https://www.apple.com/uk/imac-24/specs/). Assuming we're talking 16x9 aspect ratio:

```
(8 ^ 2) / (6 ^ 2) = 1.77777... # we must square because 4k, 8k etc refers to one dimension and there are two

60hz / 1.77777 = 33.75hz
```

In other words, with the same pixel-rate as 6kx60hz, the display system should be able to do 8k by 30hz. Question is, is this supported?

I'm very interested in buying the 8k [LG Nano 55](https://www.lg.com/uk/tvs/lg-55nano956na) and, since I'm mainly doing static graphics, the refresh rate is not too worrisome for me (I was an early adopter of 4k for the same reason and 30hz was not a dealbreaker).

Will an M1 Mac support 30hz 8k over HDMI 2.1? Might it even support it at 60hz or something in between? I've known Mac tech specs in the past to be conservative. Actually if Apple is talking about 6k with its own 6016x3384 resolution "6k" monitor, as opposed to simply expanding Full HD by three as I did above, then the above calculation compared to the LG is 36.82 hz. Basically I'm guessing/hoping that 8k would be fine, but that since Apple doesn't do an 8k monitor, it's only providing a max resolution of 6k because that's the top product it sells. But I'd love to get confirmation from someone who might have tested this in reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to be cautious. The drivers are highly tuned for Apple official specs which allow for 6016 by 3384 pixels (20.4 million pixels) at 218 pixels per inch and 60 Hz. However, I’m seeing lots of references that the M1 mini implements DisplayPort 1.4 which has bandwidth for 8K at 60 Hz.

- https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/11/11/how-apple-silicon-on-a-m1-mac-changes-monitor-support-and-what-you-can-connect

Since these are ThunderBolt 3 / USB 4 devices, you might get the display and count on a return policy if it doesn’t work well enough out of the gate. Apple also is updating the graphics drivers and Big Sur to work with these ultra wide and high pixel count monitors that are more and more common.

I don’t recommend a TV for static graphics, but assume you’ve done that research and are ok loving with or disabling all that processing (motion smoothing, AI sharpening) that comes with choosing a TV over a monitor / display. What does the vendor say would be my final decision if you can’t find a retailer that will let you test things.